# MySQL sub position counters in Query

Tags: mysql, sql, large-data

I need to get a record set where I fill the field level1 for every 60 records, means I need to fill level1 field this way:

- on pos=1 and pos=60 with level1 = 1
- on pos=61 and pos=120 with level1 = 2
- on pos=121 and pos=180 with level1 = 3

... 
**and then:** if I have let's say 630 records i must set for pos=601 and 630 level1 = 10 because I don't have 660 records the 630th record finished the level.

Has anyone a idea how this can be done in a clean way?

```
SET @pos:=0; 
SET @posrel:=0;
SET @level1:=0;
SELECT id, member_id, member_name, pos, @posrel:=@posrel+1 AS posrel, @level1:=@level1+??? AS level1
FROM
(
  SELECT id, member_id, LEFT(member_name, LENGTH(member_name)-36) AS member_name, @pos:=@pos+1 AS pos FROM member_directory WHERE member_name_first= 'A'
) AS directory_listing
HAVING pos % 60 IN(0,1);
```

Comment: This is not for paging, right? Because if it is, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @Adrian: no, it's used for a directory listing (seo). there we have above 100m records and need to split them into multiple levels for the listing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- SET @pos:=0;   //Can be moved inside the query.
-- SET @posrel:=0; 
SELECT inner.*, posrel DIV 60 as level1 FROM (
  SELECT directory_listing.*, @posrel:=@posrel+1 AS posrel  AS level1
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      id
      , member_id
      , LEFT(member_name, LENGTH(member_name)-36) AS member_name_first
      , @pos:=@pos+1 AS pos 
    FROM member_directory
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @pos:= 0) x1  
    WHERE member_name_first = 'A'
    AND directory_listing.pos < 120
  ) directory_listing
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @posrel:= 0) x2
) inner
```

Or maybe

```
-- SET @pos:=0;   //Can be moved inside the query.
-- SET @posrel:=0; 
SELECT inner.*, posrel DIV 60 as level1 FROM (
  SELECT directory_listing.*, @posrel:=@posrel+1 AS posrel  AS level1
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      id
      , member_id
      , LEFT(member_name, 1) AS member_name_first
      , @pos:=@pos+1 AS pos 
    FROM member_directory
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @pos:= 0) x1  
    WHERE member_name LIKE 'A%'
    AND directory_listing.pos < 120
  ) directory_listing
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @posrel:= 0) x2
) inner
```

Comment: It look's very well, I will test it in the next 30min (the server is busy at the moment) and let you know

Comment: both query fails ...for the right syntax to use near 'inner.*, posrel DIV 60 as level1 FROM (
  SELECT directory_listing.*, @posrel:=@' at line 1 any idea?

Comment: i fixed the query, but it don't deliver what it needs, the pos field is not longer correct, the recordset is only 60 records and the level is filled for every row. any help is welcome :-)